# iOS Glint Effect Text

Tags: ios

How would one implement a text glint effect similar to the Slide to Unlock image, or in the Paypal app?

Is it possible to have transparent text and animate some sort of white shape moving behind it?

Comment: You're probably going to need to look at Core Text rather than something like UILabel. Beyond that I'm afraid I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [MTAnimatedLabel](https://github.com/mturner1721/MTAnimatedLabel) which does the exact same thing.

He uses a CATextLayer to mask a CAGradientLayer and then he animates the gradient layer for the required effect.

You can find the usage details in the link. You can even change the tint color.